# What is the best way to display/navigate a content-heavy XML file?

Tags: xml

I have very large XML files. There are some main trees within it such as "views", "roles", "users", "spreadsheets", "instances", "classes", etc.

I am wanting to create a way that I can easily view and navigate these XML files. This would involve having a menu that includes links such as "views", "instances", etc and also links within the content (such as when viewing a list of instances of a class, I can click on an instance to view it's attributes).

What would be the best to go about this? I have learned XSLT to some extent, and can get all of the content using for-each and value-of's and such... but I don't want just one huge page.

Some thoughts I've had..

1. I currently have the XSL sheet linked to the XML like href="xmlTestStyle.xsl"
   would there be a way (or would it make sense) to apply different XSL sheets for the same XML document, and the links would just be to use a different XSL sheet?
2. Is there a way to use AJAX to pull certain data (xpath) from an XML document?

I'm pretty new to this type of thing, so please try to explain any ideas/solutions for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's always hard to answer design questions without a great deal of background on the project requirements. It's not clear from your description whether you want to do the work client side or server side. It also depends a bit what you mean by "very large". Is that 2Mb or 2Gb? Certainly (unless the XML is *really* big) this looks like quite a good use case for client-side XSLT processing - pull the XML off the server once, then navigate around it by presenting different views of the data obtained by applying different stylesheets and/or the same stylesheet with different parameters (there's an example of this approach using genealogy data as a worked case study in my XSLT reference book, though it's a little dated - very much Web 1.0!).

Comment: Well, the total size will vary depending on the size of the dataset it represents... but I don't think we'd be looking at gigs. Just that its big enough that its hard to look at easily without being able to navigate through it with links and menus and such.

I'd like to be able to just open these in a browser from an XML file on the computer, so client side stuff. An example would be like if I were to click on "views" it would do a for-each of views/view and have links, where if i clicked on one of the views. I would then see information about that particular view.